# yast2 crashes on opensuse tumbleweed 20230911

Tags: opensuse, yast

i start yast2 from system menue: system/YaST Software

i get details for an application, e.g. thunderbird. when i press 'accept'

it starts up the installing packages screen, then just crashes. This happens with all applications at the moment